# Tailwind CSS overflow for flex items

Tags: html, css, reactjs, tailwind-css

I am trying to render cards above a map (map z-index is -1). The cards are in a flex container and I want to show an overflow scrollbar on the x-axis, but the cards flow beyond the screen width.

[image: over flow problem]

My code is below:

1. Map Container (in `Map.js`)

```css
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: -1;
```

2. Card

```html
<div className="border box-border m-0 ring-gray-500 bg-yellow-100 rounded border-gray-400 h-36 w-64 p-2"></div>
```

3. `App.js`

```
<section className="p-1">
      <div className="absolute top-1 flex flex-row flex-grow-0 overflow-auto justify-items-start align-middle gap-1 ">
        <Card />
        <Card />
        <Card />
          ...
      </div>
    <Map/>
</section>
```

Comment: I have also tried ```max-w-screen``` on card container div but it shrinks the card sizes

Comment: Try to give the `section` tag a specific `width` and give the `div` with the cards a `w-full`.

Comment: @SeifAlaa i tried ```w-64``` on ```section``` and ```w-full``` on cards container ```div```. but it shrank the size of cards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I fixed my problem. thanks to @Seif Alaa for the idea.

1. I fixed the size of main container `section` with `w-screen`
2. In cards container `div` i inherited the size with `w-full`
3. Stopped the cards from shrinking with `shrink-0` on card

Comment: I tried to achieve what you want using `max-w` on the cards container here is what I tried:
https://play.tailwindcss.com/w1Hov5Eb9I

It's the same as the method you used but instead of using `shrink-0` I moved the `width` and `height` of the card to be a child.